# Unable to see the source code of Coda

Tags: reverse-engineering, coda

I read [Jeff's blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001072.html) that someone had managed to see a closed source code by a program called Reflector.

I would like see the source code of Coda, which is a shareware app. 
However, I am not sure which application I should use for that. It seems that Reflector can only be used for. Net apps.

**How can you see the source code of Coda?**

Comment: Reflector does not produce the source code of a program; it produces code which *could compile to the same IL* as the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflector only works with managed .NET assemblies (CIL binaries)

Answer (score 2):

Your best chance would be getting a job as a Software Engineer at [panic](http://www.panic.com).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Coda is shareware. It's a commercial application that has a trial period.

Comment: Coda still seems to have some closed parts such as its terminal code.